# Print a random integer number between 1 and 42 (both inclusive) to the console

Tags: javascript

I have a question in a exercise to print a random integer number between 1 and 42, but im getting an error in my console "Are you doing the multiplication inside the ceil() method call?"

My code is this one.

```
var someRandomNumber = Math.random();
var wholeRandomNumber = Math.ceil(someRandomNumber);
console.log(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 42));
```

I dont know what im doing wrong, honestly if someone can help me! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
function generateRandom(min = 0, max = 1000) {

    // find diff
    let difference = max - min;

    // generate random number 
    let rand = Math.random();

    // multiply with difference 
    rand = Math.floor( rand * difference);

    // add with min value 
    rand = rand + min;

    return rand;
}
console.log(generateRandom(min=1,max=42));
```